# Selecting element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[We need to click from 1 to 50 respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vi6a.png)

> number elements:
>
> ```
> 1 - <span class="box" style="z-index:99"></span>
> 2 - <span class="box" style="z-index:98"></span>
> 3 - <span class="box" style="z-index:97"></span>
> 4 - <span class="box" style="z-index:96"></span>
> 5 - <span class="box" style="z-index:95"></span>
> 6 - <span class="box" style="z-index:94"></span>
> 7 - <span class="box" style="z-index:93"></span>
> 8 - <span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>
> ```

```
My Code :

import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://zzzscore.com/1to50/en/?ts=1585514800920")

time.sleep(2)

element_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[style^=index]")

i = 99
while i > 50:
    element_list[i].click()
```

I want the code to click numbers from 1 to 50 respectively,
You can see the elements of the numbers in the attachment, I want to use the pattern (index 99 in element 1, index 98 in element 2...) between the elements, but I couldn't

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at 3 problems in your code.

1. `find_element_by_css_selector` returns a single element, not a list. So you won't be able iterate trough the elements. To select multiple elements use a plural form like: `find_elements_by_css_selector`
2. the provided css selector is not valid
3. it seems that you assume that you'll receive the web elements sorted by z-index which is not the case

I recommend learning Xpath, it superior and more useful than css selectors (you may use it later on when you'll have the chance to parse XMLs). But even Xpath won't sort the elements by attribute values like z-index.

What you could do however:

1. find out how many elements should be clicked
2. in a `for` cycle iterate trough from 1 to the desired max
3. inside the `for` cycle fabricate a dynamic xpath via f-string to find your element:

   - a div which contains the number you want to click as text `div[text()="{i}"]`
   - and the div in question has a span which has a box class `span[@class="box"]`

So basically `elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[text()="{i}"]/span[@class="box"]')` should be the key for your task.